# Program freezes at oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath)?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, interop, mailmerge

I have put together a simple C# Winforms Application that queries AS400 data based on user criteria and returns the results in a ListView Control. On Button_Click() I then store the Headers and Data in a .txt file. Below I am trying to use that .txt file as the DataSource for a Mail Merge word document.

When the code reaches `oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);` the program seems to just freeze up. Nothing occurs and I cannot step through to the next line. Anyone have ideas for what I am doing wrong?

```
public void Print(string docLoc, string docSource)
        {
            try
            {
                Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
                Word.Document oWrdDoc = new Word.Document();
                oWord.Visible = true;
                Object oTemplatePath = "C:\\Users\NAME\\Desktop\\B-AIAddChgDual10-06-NEW.doc";
                oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);
                Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                oWrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource("C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Test2.txt", oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
                    oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
                oWrdDoc.MailMerge.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**: Turns out I did not have the new Word instance set to `Visible = true` so when the instance brought up a dialog saying the file was locked for editing (**by myself???**) it was prompting me to open a Read-Only version, which previously I could not see, making it look like everything was frozen in processing. I've modified my code above to reflect the changes.

Any ideas for why I'm locked out of my own file, and how to prevent this?

These are the dialogs I receive after accepting open a Read-Only document (in order):

[image: Reult]
[image: Dialog1]
[image: Dialog2]
[image: Dialog3]
[image: Dialog4]
[image: Dialog5]
[image: Dialog6]
[image: Dialog7]

After selecting how to replace the fields in the above:

[image: Merge Errors]

Original Mail Merge Fields:

[image]

After Personal Selections:

[image]

How do I tell the Word Application to use the '!' character as the Field Delimiter in my C# code?

Also, how do I proceed with the dialogs? I'm assuming I receive each one due to my datasource not containing fields matching those listed as Mail Merge Fields?

Here are my Mail Merge Fields:

**-fuldate
-sys
-memno
-name
-address1
-address2
-address3
-sal**

And here are my Delimited fields from my .txt DataSource file:

**memno!name!addr1!addr2!city!state!zip!old_addr1!old_addr2!old_city!old_state!old_zip**

Comment: Which version of MS-Office you are using?

Comment: 2010. Solved initial problem if you wish to review my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `OpenAndRepair` Mode to `True` and then Open the Document

**Replace this:**

```
oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);
```

**With following:**

```
oWrdDoc =  word.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath, OpenAndRepair: true);
```

Comment: Turns out the instance was not visible, so I was not seeing the dialog asking me if I wanted to open a read-only copy since the document was, for some reason, locked. See my EDIT for additional info.

Comment: oh great you solved it by yourself :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: Well, I solved that issue, but if you see my EDIT I've got a lot of pesky dialogs :) How do I code in C# to tell it to use my '!' character as Field Delimiter?